# Обводка текста в Firefox жирная, а в Chrome еле видна. Почему и как исправить?

Tags: css

Вот код:

```
text-shadow: #ffffff 1px 0px, #ffffff 1px 1px, #ffffff 0px 1px, #ffffff -1px 1px, #ffffff -1px 0px, #ffffff -1px -1px, #ffffff 0px -1px, #ffffff 1px -1px, #ffffff 0 0 3px, #ffffff 0 0 3px, #ffffff 0 0 3px, #ffffff 0 0 3px, #ffffff 0 0 3px, #ffffff 0 0 3px, #ffffff 0 0 3px, #ffffff 0 0 3px;
```

Comment: Это что такое? Где вы такое используете?

Comment: забить. в разных браузерах размытие работает по-разному.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

> Как-то можно решить эту проблему?

нет. в разных браузерах размытие работает по-разному.